# How do I get Mathematica to simplify my expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
Laplacian[x/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (8 x^3)/(x^2 + y^2)^3 + (8 x y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^3 - (8 x)/(x^2 + y^2)^2
> ```

```
% === 0

False
```

Since we have $$\frac{8x^3}{(x^2+y^2)^3}+\frac{8xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3}-\frac{8x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

we can turn the third term to $\frac{(x^2+y^2)8x}{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)^2}$, and simplify this whole expression to get zero.

How can I get Mathematica to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX -- and certainly not as W|A url input -- so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry Michael, I'm a newbie in Mathematica.SE! I have updated my question.

Comment: You have to simplify the expression by using `Simplify` command.

Comment: @AnjanKumar Thanks very much. I got 0 by `Simplify`. But why `===` can't evaluate it?

Comment: Checking for equality doesn't simplify expressions to the full. For example, `x-x===0` returns `True`, whereas, `1/(1 + a) - a/(a + a^2) === 0 ` returns `False`. Therefore, it is better to explicitly use `Simplify`.

Comment: `===` is the infix form of [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html).  You can check the documentation for what it does.  It doesn't make any algebraic simplifications.

Comment: I got it, thank to everyone.